# 14.04 Trusty+Gnome: how do I add application icons onto the top panel?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, gnome-panel

Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, Gnome.
How do I add application icons on the top panel?

This is what I had on Precise:

[image: This was on Precise]

And this is what I have on Trusty:

[image: This is on Trusty]

I tried icon dragging and the right click, but they only launch the application.

EDIT: note that this question is about Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, the thing that worked in previous releases (such as Precise) does not work anymore.

Comment: That looks like gnome-flashback - therefore this is a duplicate with the answer there that will work

Comment: The 2011 answer is irrelevant. The Alt+Click thing does not work in Trusty (did you try it yourself?) Please undo the duplicate mark.

Comment: if you are using flashback with compiz note the comment - its Meta + Alt + right-click  and yes, I did check before marking as a duplicate.

Comment: **SOLUTION:** `sudo aptitude install gnome-session-flashback`, then log in choosing the compiz flashback. Still no idea how that would work without flashback.

Comment: With Ubuntu **Gnome**, not Ubuntu with Gnome flashback, this method does not work.  I could find no combination of any modifier keys with right click that worked.  I personally am very well aware of the old method, but it simply does not work.  Some of you need better reading comprehension.